# Plot: Show specific values in y axis

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I need to plot a list of points and I am using ListLinePlot. Mathematica decides which values on the y axis need to be shown in the graph. Instead, how can I show in the y axis the exact values for each point? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `Ticks` to specify tick-marks on the axes. For example:

```
data = RandomInteger[100, 10];
ListLinePlot[data, Ticks -> {Automatic, {3, 7, 20, 38, 66, 99}}]
```

The use of `Automatic` allows Mathematica to set the ticks on the x-axis, while the list given is the y-axis. Of course, you want to actually use your data-set as the ticks, so:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Ticks -> {Automatic, data}]
```

Note that these may overlap if you have two data-points that are too close together. You haven't given your data or any information about it, so I can't assess whether this is something that matters to you.